# compare datetime with different timezone_type php

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to compare to DateTime objects in PHP.

```
$Time1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('UP', '1409900072+0200');

$Time2 = new DateTime('2014-09-05 07:54:32');
```

The Time2 use the defoult which is Europe/Copenhagen, comparing yields the following

```
if ($Time2 > $Time1){
    echo "true \n";
} else {
    echo "false \n";
}

true 
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2014-09-05 06:54:32"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+02:00"
}
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2014-09-05 07:54:32"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
   int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(17) "Europe/Copenhagen"
 }
```

The way I understand it is the actual local time for Time1 is 08:54:32, so how can I get the comparison at the same timezone?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is, what is `1409900072` doing with a `+0200` anyway? A UNIX timestamp does not need an accompanying timezone; so what exactly is the meaning of it? Also, `+0200` is pretty useless information for most purposes; a timezone needs to be specified by name to be really useful.

Comment: @deceze - Agreed, but these are found in some places, such as in data serialized from older ASP.Net JSON implementations where the value looks something like `"/Date(1198908717056-0700)/"`.  In that particular case the value is in milliseconds, and the offset is extra data.  The ms value doesn't reflect the offset.  Compare this with ISO8601, where an offset means that the value has *already* been adjusted by the offset.  No wonder PHP is confused here.  @Mads - Some detail about where this format of input is coming from would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson - The complete timestamp is as you have shown /Date(1409900072+0200)/ and it is an output from a webshop system from Dandomain.dk. The time is when an order is created in the shopping system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The really weird part is your initial value of `1409900072+0200`. If `1409900072` is a UNIX timestamp, passing a particular timezone with it makes little sense. And it seems to cause PHP to create the instance incorrectly; it creates the instance with the time set to the UTC value (6:54), but the timezone offset of +0200 (where the time should actually be 8:54).

Arguably this should be filed as a bug report; but arguably the input data is nonsensical to begin with.

If you're feeding in a UNIX timestamp, then ignore any timezone information it may contain and explicitly set the timezone to UTC, then it all works as expected:

```
$t1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('U+', '1409900072+0200', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$t2 = new DateTime('2014-09-05 07:54:32', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Copenhagen'));

var_dump($t1 > $t2); // true
```

Note that PHP [before 5.3.9](http://3v4l.org/5ZtlH) seems to have problems with the `createFromFormat` call; you'll probably have to filter out the trailing timezone by hand if you need to support those versions.

Comment: Thanks for your comments i understand the problematics with this now. I have decided to only use the UNIX timestamp part for now, since including the +0200 causes some challenges elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Convert both DateTimes to UTC (`setTimeZone('UTC')`) and then compare them.

```
<?php
$Time1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('UP', '1409900072+0200');
$Time2 = new DateTime('2014-09-05 07:54:32');

// convert
$utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');

$time1_utc = clone $Time1;
$time1_utc->setTimeZone($utc);

$time2_utc = clone $Time2;
$time2_utc->setTimeZone($utc);

var_dump($Time1,$Time2);
var_dump($time1_utc,$time2_utc);
```

Comment: If you do this on both, it converts Time1 to `2014-09-05 04:54:32`, which is wrong.

Comment: why is it wrong? it was specified with +2h from UTC

Comment: The UNIX timestamp 1409900072 represents 2014-09-05 06:54:32 UTC time.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point but it was not supposed to give DateTime a timestamp and a deviation. Given that the computation looks "good".